# Reference for cool exercises on Integrals

Tags: calculus, reference-request, power-series, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am giving tutorials in calculus and looking for interesting exercises on:

1. integrals (over finite and infinite domains, convergence questions etc.)
2. Series
3. double integrals
   I have many more or less standard exercises but I would like to present some cool ones. I would be happy for suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: You could always look here http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf However, it is not translated into English yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some interesting books about integrals or integration techniques, they contain exercises:

- *Irresistible integrals* of Boros and Moll.
- *Inside interesting integrals* of Nahin.
- *Improper Riemann integrals* of Roussos.
- *Lebesgue integration on Euclidean space* of Jones.
- *Advanced integration techniques* of Alyafeai (I think this last book doesn't contain exercises but it probably will be very interesting to you).

to cite someones. There are other asked questions similar to this one, try to find them with the search bar.

Also there are several books devoted to integration theory, specialized in different areas.

Comment: I'm also interested in a book on challenging integrals and to learn some new techniques. My level is that of a good first year's student. Do you think Boros's and Moll's book would be on the appropriate level? I can only find the table of contents and the first chapter online. If so, I'll buy the book :)

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov maybe you will see many repeated content in this book, but there are some topics in the table of contents that I never hear of. I didnt read any of these books, maybe some chapter of someone, but I listed here because I remembered it names.

Comment: also unfortunately I dont know any book devoted to series and convergence

Comment: I was thinking the level might be too high because I found one integral from the book that was especially hard. But in that case i'll buy the book since surely it contains much I don't know of yet. Thank you!

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Im not in contact with the university teaching of mathematics so I cant know if for a first year student this book will be so hard or so easy

Comment: No problem, I think it contains interesting new material and if it's too hard I'll read it later. Thanks for the reference!